# How to link a Visio drawing to a specific region or table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I would like to place a table in Visio that is directly linked to the actual table in Excel. That way it will show the information I want and update it in the Visio diagram when it is updated in Excel.

However, the best I can do is link it to an excel doc and have it result in pulling a random set of rows and columns from the current sheet that I have open at the time.

I thought I had solved my problem when I found this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/link-visio-drawing-to-a-specific-region#:%7E:text=Navigate%20to%20your%20Excel%20workbook,drawing%20and%20another%20program%27s%20file.). However, once I reached step 10 I became confused. I don't even have an Edit menu (in Excel OR Visio; although I believe it is referring to Excel). I'd like to think that maybe this is referring to an old version of Excel, but at the top of the page it says that the article was at least upgraded this year.

So with that being said, can someone either provide guidance to where this 'Edit' menu is that contains the options the step is referring to? OR if someone has another way to show a table in Visio that is directly linked to Excel, that would also be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do the test on Microsoft Visio plan 2, I do not find **Links** option directly, but I search the "links" and then I find it!

[image]

Then you may click Change Source and enter the Item Name for embedded object.

[image]

Please note, on Change Source dialog, you need to choose the workbook first, then in Item Name box, you may enter the worksheet name, add "!", and then add the Name you need and which was defined in this worksheet.

After setting, if you click Change Source again, you would find the item name included in path.

Answer (score 0):

After step 9, try this:

Right click on the linked Excel table in the Visio file.
Select Linked Worksheet Object > Links

For step 12, click the "Item" button in the file open dialog box to be able to enter the name of the named range. I found I had to reselect the file at this point too, before clicking OK.

Hope this helps (I did the above steps in Word because I don't have Visio on the machine in front of me, but this OLE should work the same across Office).

Comment: Unfortunately Visio only adds a tab that says ‘Picture Format’ as opposed to what you seem to be getting in Word. Frustrating as what you’re seeing in Word makes a lot of sense... but it doesn’t seem to transfer over.

Comment: No additional ribbon tab added in Word (which is what I was expecting), you have to do it from the right click context menu, it seems.

Comment: Fair enough, I misread your answer. Still an issue though. When right clicking and going to ‘Linked Worksheet Object’ it only provides the options ‘Edit’, ‘Open’, and ‘Convert’. Edit and Open basically just go to the sheet itself.